Can I use integrated cable stop from clamp-on downtube shifter in thumb shifter conversion?
I have an old Raleigh steel frame that I'm converting from clamp-on downtube shifters to thumb shifters. Trying to work out cable stops, as no braze ons to bolt any converters on to.
The existing clamp-on shifters have an integral cable stop, so wondering if I can just use this as the cable stop for thumb shifters (bypassing the actual downtube shifter lever), and fit an inline barrel adjuster for tension adjustment?

Several options exist:

As described, use the existing shifters as cable stops.  Downside, it could look ugly.  The levers may be useful to someone else in an unmolested state.  An inline barrel adjuster is a good idea.

Take the shifters off, and use a clamp-on (aka band-on) cable stop like this.  Downside, it may not suit the look you're going for.


PROBLEM SOLVERS DUAL CABLE BACKSTOP Stock Code: PSBR-BR5455 

Simplify the bike by going for a full length housing and you won't need cable stops.  Downside, securing housing to a bike may also look ugly.   One workaround here is to colour match the outer housing to your frame's paint.   I've printed cable bosses in the past and secured them to the frame with cable ties or epoxy.

Internally-route the full length outers - though this means drilling holes in the frame and risks compromising the frame's strength.   Not recommended, just added for completeness.


When you're done, please do add a photo of the finished job.
